# Irreducible representations in group theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, quantum-mechanics, irreducible-representation

I am currently working through a chapter of my quantum mechanics textbook about how group theory relates to quantum mechanics (I considered asking this question on the physics exchange, but figured you all would know more). In the discussion, they prove the following theorem: if the representation of a group $G$ of order $h$ is a direct sum of irreducible representations $i$ with size $l_i$, then $$\sum_il_i^2=h.$$When I tried to test this theorem on some common groups, though, it seems to fall apart. Specifically, consider the group of symmetry transformations $C_{3v}$, the symmetry transformations of an equilateral triangle (three reflections, two rotations, and the identity). If we select the basis functions $f_1=x$, $f_2=y$ and $f_3=z$, the text showed that the representation of this group is the direct sum of a two-dimensional irreducible representation relating $f_1$ and $f_2$ and a one-dimensional irreducible representation for $f_3$ (this is pretty obvious, since transformations in the $xy$-plane don't change $z$). However, it seems like the application of the formula mentioned above should yield that $1^2+2^2=h$ ($1$ and $2$ being the dimensions of the irreducible representations). But $1^2+2^2$ is $5$, whereas $h$ is $6$ in this case, so the theorem seems to fail. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The representations in QM are as far as I know representations of the Lie algebras of the considered Lie groups. Physicists hide it behind words like "generators" which basically means tangent vectors. In any case, the representations are either of the form $G\rightarrow GL(V)$ for groups or $\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ for the Lie algebras. Since most groups in QM are semisimple, the representations split into $G\rightarrow GL(V)=\oplus_k GL(V_k).$ In your case, we have $\dim V=h$ and $\dim V_k=l_k.$ ...

Comment: ... Hence the $h\times h$ matrices of $GL(V)$ split into block matrices of size $l_k\times l_k.$ The key is semisimple, or simple! Use $SU(2)$ as group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting confused about what the theorem is saying. It says that the sum of the squares of *all* the irreducible representations equals the order of the group.

You took a single representation of $C_{3v}$ and decomposed it into 2 irreducible representations of dimensions 1 and 2. However, these are not *all* the irreducible representations of $C_{3v}$! Besides the two you have listed, there is one more irreducible representation of $C_{3v}$. It is the one-dimensional representation which sends rotations to 1 and reflections to -1 (called the alternating representation).  So in total we have $1^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 = 6$ as expected.